# Connection error on curl in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, curl, javascript-framework

Hi I am currently trying to learn how to create a backend for my app but when trying to create a port 3000 and having curl it produces this error:

NodeTutorial git:(master) ✗ `curl -v http://localhost:3000` - the connection is refused.

Please Help.

My code in my `index.js` is as follows:

```
var http = require('http'),
express = require('express');

var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>');
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: This one works fine with me

Comment: The code looks fine did you check if you have a firewall in between?

Answer (score 0):

Seems your server has not started, try running below steps and see if you are able to connect or not:

**Step 1:** Create a directory which will contain all the files related to our app and execute npm init:

```
$ mkdir nodejs-server
$ npm init
```

**Step 2:** Install [`Express`](https://expressjs.com/) as a dependency:

```
$ cd nodejs-server
$ npm install --save express
```

**Step 3:** Create default entry point for `Node.js` i.e `index.js`, inside the same directory we created:

```
$ cd nodejs-server
$ touch index.js
```

Copy the content you have shown in your question in `index.js`:

```
var http = require('http'),
express = require('express');

var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>');
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

**Step 4:** Move to directory nodejs-server and start the app following below command:

```
$ cd nodejs-server
$ node index.js
```